# How to include all .less files in angular-cli.json styles section?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-cli

So the problem I have is that each time after I create a new component, I have to remember to add it's `.less` stylesheet to `angular-cli.json` file. What I'd really like to have is to somehow tell angular to just rebuild all `.less` files wherever in src they are. I tried doing something like this:

```
{
    "apps": [
        {
            ...
            "styles": [
                "**/*.less"
            ],
            ...
        }
    ]
}
```

But I'm getting

> `module not found error`

Any help?

Comment: It's not related - I'm not asking about building .less files in general, but about automatically bundling whatever (.less, .sass or .css) style sheet files I have. Please read my question thoroughly and remove the duplicate marking :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> each time after I create a new **component**, I have to remember to add it's .less stylesheet to angular-cli.json

No need.

The Components are imported in *app.module.ts* and also added to `imports[]`.

**angular-cli.json include only the global stylesheet *styles.less* and the stylesheets from npm packages.**

it will be added automatically when you install a package via npm

If your default style extension is not less,

in angular-cli.json, in the below code

```
"defaults": {
    "styleExt": "css",
    "component": {}
}
```

replace the css with less that is

```
"defaults": {
    "styleExt": "less",
    "component": {}
}
```

Comment: I was like 200000% sure that we also have to add component's styles to `angular-cli` file. Very silly of me :). Thanks!